# Alphabetically sorted numbers

Tags: ruby, sorting

This exercise involves taking an array of numbers and sorting them alphabetically. For example, [1,2,3,4] would return as [4,1,3,2]

I mapped the array first, returning an array of words, then sorted those words using Ruby's built-in sort function. Then, I mapped that array to return an array of integers.

It works, obviously. I want your suggestions and thoughts, different ideas and better ways I could do this in the future.

I know I could one-line the map functions, but thought this is better for readability. Example: `alphabeticize = numbers.map {|num| alphas.fetch(:"#{num.to_s}")}.sort`

```
def alphabetic_number_sort(numbers)
  alphas = {"0": "zero", "1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three", "4": "four", "5": "five", "6": "six", "7": "seven", "8": "eight", "9": "nine", "10": "ten", "11": "eleven", "12": "twelve", "13": "thirteen", "14": "fourteen", "15": "fifteen", "16": "sixteen", "17": "seventeen", "18": "eighteen", "19": "nineteen"}

  alphabeticize = numbers.map do |num|
    alphas.fetch(:"#{num.to_s}")
  end.sort

  sorted_alphabetically = alphabeticize.map do |word|
    alphas.key(word).to_s.to_i
  end

  return sorted_alphabetically
end

p alphabetic_number_sort((0..19).to_a) == [
  8, 18, 11, 15, 5, 4, 14, 9, 19, 1, 7, 17,
  6, 16, 10, 13, 3, 12, 2, 0
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort_by` cleans this up quite a bit, and avoids the unnecessary conversions to and from strings:

```
def sort_alphabetically(numbers)
  alphas = %w(zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen)
  .map.with_index {|x,i| [i, x]}.to_h

  numbers.sort_by {|x| alphas[x]}
end
```

Notes:

1. Point on naming: use a verb, or else a noun describing what the function returns: `sort_alphabetically` or `alphabetically_sorted`. I know technically `alphabetically_sorted` isn't a noun, but I see it as an abbreviation for `alphabetically_sorted_list`, which is too verbose.
2. If speed matters, you should compute the hash outside the function, so it's only done once.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I will study this further. 

Also, I think I accidentally "down voted" you answer :/

Answer (score 1):

When defining the `alphas` hash, I would consider strings to be more appropriate as keys than [symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36513996/1157100).  That would help eliminate the awkward colon during lookup in `alphas.fetch(:"#{num.to_s}")`.

However, I question the need for a hash at all.  Why not write it as an array?

```
ENGLISH_NUMS = %w(
  zero one two three four five six seven eight nine
  ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen
)
```

Then, it's a simple matter of using [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

```
def alphabetic_number_sort(numbers)
  numbers.sort_by { |n| ENGLISH_NUMS[n] }
end
```

Note that it is common practice to omit the explicit `return` in Ruby.